# Custom style of Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts

I am trying to style the default contact form i have imported into my theme, but it is not responding to any changes i make to the css.  The form is in the footer of the page: http://jteng.ayomo.com

Any suggestions on how i can manipulate this form??

Thanks

The css I currently have is as follows but is not showing on the form:

```
}
.wpcf7-form-control,
select,
textarea,
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="datetime"],
input[type="datetime-local"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="month"],
input[type="time"],
input[type="week"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="color"],
.uneditable-input {
height: 200px;
width:500px;
background-color:#999;
}
```

http://jteng.ayomo.com

Comment: Provide the link to your css file, I couldn't find that code in any CSS file called in source-code.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74505439/theme.css

Comment: So, that page doesn't point to any `theme.css` file, it just points to `theme.min.css` and that file doesn't have the css that you provided. Looking for `.uneditable-input` in `http://jteng.ayomo.com/wp-content/themes/lambda/assets/css/theme.min.css?ver=4.4.2` file you'll see that the css rules applied are different. A theme's cache problem, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for that Felipe as I was in the wrong style sheet.  However I have since solved this problem with a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact Form 7 style is a great plugin to style your contact forms without the need to go in and fiddle with the css:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-style/